# Circular model references

Tags: django, model

I am not quite sure about the best/idiomatic way to approach the following:

I have a model called ***BlogPost*** and a model called ***BlogPostContent***. BlogPost has a field called ***CurrentContent*** which references a related record in the BlogPostContent table. BlogPostContent has a foreign key field called *Post* referencing its related BlogPost.

When a blog is modified, a new BlogPostContent record is created, and the BlogPost is updated such that its ***CurrentContent*** field references the newest BlogPostContent. I do this so it is possible to provide a way to *rollback* and specify any ***BlogPostContent*** record to use the ***CurrentContent***

It is possible for the ***CurrentContent*** to reference ANY of the BlogPostContent records related to it.

If I were to model this in code, it would be:

```
class BlogPostContent {
   //Content
}

class BlogPost {
  BlogPostContent currentPost;
  List<BlogPostContent> contentHistory;
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider using something like [django-simple-history](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history) to manage your history, rather than this approach. That app tracks historical data on a model for you automatically, and allows you to easily access past data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a foreign key back to `BlogPost` from `BlogPostContent` for your content history.

```
class BlogPostContent(models.Model):
    blog_post = models.ForeignKey('BlogPost', related_name='content_history')

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    current_post = models.ForeignKey('BlogPostContent')
```

Then you can access both the history or the current post from a blog post instance like this:

```
blogpost.content_history.all()
blogpost.current_post
```

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the answer. Makes perfect sense.